# What is the difference between searchkick and elasticsearch-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch

These both seem to be very active and fairly popular elastic search gems for rails.  It seems like the major difference is that searchkick has more customization based on individual users.

What are the differences that one would want to consider before choosing which one to use?

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails

```
*s 872
fork 165
latest commit 2.5 months ago
```

https://github.com/ankane/searchkick

```
*s 1,594
fork 165
latest commit 11 days ago
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Searchkick is much more Rails friendly gem, they have features to get autocomplete for example and don't force you to learn guts of ElasticSearch to do basic stuff.

Also, looks like guy who wrote searchkick use it himself in Rails vs Elasticsearch-rails is just library for one more language for ElasticSearch team.

I started with Elasticsearch-rails and migrated to searchkick myself.

Answer (score 1):

`elasticsearch-rails`
is maintained by group of people working in Elasticsearch.org.

All libraries for Elasticsearch for different languages are using similar patern, so if you switch for example to python, structure of it's library will be simmilar.